# Expected value - Transition Matrix

Tags: probability, expectation, transition-matrix

"Let X(t) be a discrete time Markov chain with state space {0,1,2} and
 transition matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1/3&1/3&1/3\\1/3&1/3&1/3\\1/3&1/3&1/3 \end{bmatrix}
Find the expected value of the time it takes the chain to move from state 0 to state
2."

Here is the answer: 
E0→2 = 1 + (1/3) · 0 + (1/3) · E0→2 +(1/3)·E1→2 = 1+(2/3)·E0→2 = 3.

I find it hard to understand what this means.
Is there someone who can explain this clearly to me?

Comment: This is a standard result to compute hitting times of a DTMC. Are you working out of a book? Surely, this theorem is covered.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_0=0$ and $\tau = \inf\{n>0:X_n=2\}$. Observe that $P^2=P$ and hence $P^n=P$ for any positive integer $n$. It follows then that $\tau\sim\mathrm{Geo}\left(\frac13\right)$, that is, $$
\mathbb P(\tau = k) = \frac13\left(\frac23\right)^{k-1},\ k=1,2,\ldots.
$$
The expected value of $\tau$ is thus computed by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\tau] &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\ \mathbb P(\tau = k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\ \frac13\left(\frac23\right)^{k-1}\\
&= \frac13\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\left(\frac23\right)^k\\
&=\frac13\left(1-\frac23\right)^{-2}\\
&= 3.
\end{align}

More generally, define
\begin{align}
\tau_0&=\inf\{n\geqslant0:X_n=2\mid X_0=0\}\\
\tau_1&=\inf\{n\geqslant0:X_n=2\mid X_0=1\}\\
\tau_2&=\inf\{n\geqslant0:X_n=2\mid X_0=2\}.
\end{align}
Clearly $\tau_2=0$, and by the Markov property we have the system of linear equations
\begin{align}
\tau_0 &= 1 + \frac13\tau_0 + \frac13\tau_1\\
\tau_1 &= 1 + \frac13\tau_0 + \frac13\tau_1,
\end{align}
which yields $\tau_0=\tau_1=3$.